# What is the limit of the below functions when n tends to inifinity?

Tags: limits, asymptotics, infinity

What is the value for the functions in the image when limit n tends to infinity?. Also what is the asymptotic complexity (big $O$ notation) for all the four functions?.

$$\begin{aligned}f_1(n) &= (n^{0.999999})\log n \\
  f_2(n) &= 10000000  n\\
  f_3(n) &= 1.000001^n\\
  f_4(n) &= n^2\end{aligned}$$

Comment: First of all, welcome. Second, you shouldn't expect anyone here to do this for you. You must first expose what you know, what you have tried, and the problems you have doing these. Third, always try to format mathematical expressions, I did for you, please see the code to see how.

Comment: The limit for $n\rightarrow \infty$ does not exist in any of the functions.

Comment: By complexity of the function, do you mean the complexity to compute the function? or do you mean what is the function's asymptotic growth rate?

Comment: @Peter, or, I assume you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{i}(n)=\infty$ for each function $f_{i}(n)$...

Answer (score 0):

It is readily apparent from the definition that
\begin{align}
f_1(n) &\in \mathcal O(n^{0.999999})\log n\\
f_2(n) &\in \mathcal O(n)\\
f_3(n) &\in \mathcal O(1.000001^n)\\
f_4(n) &\in \mathcal O(n^2).
\end{align}

I will use $f_2$ as an example. Put $C = 10000000$ and $n_0=1$. Then for any integer $n\geqslant n_0$,
$$f_2(n) = 10000000n \leqslant Cn,$$
so that $f_2(n)\in\mathcal O(n)$.